# How to combine multiple tbox commands into one command

Tags: tcolorbox

I have the following code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, drop shadow={black,opacity=1}]
\subsubsection{Méthode1.3}
Soit G un groupe, noté multiplicativement, et soit $a\in G$. Pour déterminer l'ordre de l'élément $a$, on peut:

\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

\end{document}

which generates something like,

[image]

However, of course it would be an overkill to type

> ```
> \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, drop shadow={black,opacity=1}]
> ```

every time

Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to redefine the command in some way (perhaps using \newtcolorbox), so that I do not need to type

**[enhanced, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, drop shadow={black,opacity=1}]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is what `\newtcolorbox` is for.

Here is the output with `tcolorbox` and the `MyBox` enviroment defined via `\newtcolorbox`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\pagecolor{white}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{MyBox}[1][]{%
    enhanced, 
    sharp corners,
    colback=white, 
    colframe=black, 
    drop shadow={black,opacity=1},
    #1
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced, 
    sharp corners, 
    colback=white, 
    colframe=black, 
    drop shadow={black,opacity=1},
]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{MyBox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{MyBox}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was putting those options in one of the [ ] before { } in the \newtcolorbox